# What is "Create Method Probe" and how can I use it?

Tags: jfr, jmc, java-mission-control

The context menu of a stack frame in the Java Mission Control UI has an entry "Create Method Probe". It brings up a dialog where I can enter a "Preset Name". Clicking "ok" nothing happens.

[image: screenshot]

What is this probe supposed to do and how can I use it? Where can I find it after closing the dialog?

Comment: I think the configuration that is created is for the JMC agent. See https://github.com/openjdk/jmc/tree/master/agent

Comment: Good find @KireHaglin, thank you. Looks like it should create the XML description of event probes that is mentioned on the linked page. Now I need to figure out where it ends up being saved as I couldn't find it so far.